# Showing p's are the same for $P_{i,j}$ and $P^k_{i,j}$

Tags: probability

Intuitively this makes sense. The probabilities of $P_{i,j}$ will clearly be the same as $P^k_{i,j}$ since these probabilities are essentially the entries of the matrix when taking the $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}$ of the power of both matrices. They will clearly have the same entries since one is just a power of the other.

I am not sure that this is enough of a justification and was hoping someone could help me out with showing this more rigoroursly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stationary distribution of a finite Markov chain is an eigenvector $d$ of its transition matrix. Therefore
$$ P_{i,j} d = d \implies P_{i,j}^k d = d \implies Q_{i,j} d = d$$
for every positive integer $k$, so every stationary distribution of $P_{i,j}$ is a stationary distribution of $Q_{i,j}$.

For the opposite direction, one would have to show that every eigenvector of $P_{i,j}^k$ is an eigenvector of $P_{i,j}$. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: I see what you did. That is clever and easy. But would it not be $d^k$. Check out this link https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_of_Matrix_Powers

Comment: We are consider eigenvectors, not eigenvalues. It is only the eigenvalues that are raised to the power of $k$. What we are doing is essentially this:
$$ P^k d = P^{k-1} P d = P^{k-1} d = \cdots = Pd = d.$$
To be on the safe side, you could use an induction, but that only obscures the matter.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you know that $ P_{i,j} d = d \implies P_{i,j}^k d=d $. It is not obvious to me why that is a true statement?

Comment: Use induction over $k$. For $k = 1$, it is simply the statement that $d$ is a stationary distribution. Next, assume that $P_{i,j}^k d = d$ for some $k \geq 1$. Then
$$ P_{i,j}^{k + 1} d = P_{i,j}^k (P_{i,j} d ) = P_{i,j}^k d = d $$
since $d$ is an eigenvector of $P_{i,j}$. This finished the induction.